# Fetch API only updates database in chrome, not IE

Tags: angular, typescript, api, fetch-api, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to make an API call on browser and tab close. Fetch API is the only way I've gotten the API call to work correctly. My problem is that the database only updates when using chrome. When I use IE it doesn't seem to want to update. This function is in an Angular app within the app.component.ts file. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(): void {
    require('es6-promise').polyfill();
    require('isomorphic-fetch');

    fetch('https://localhost:44341/api/v1/user-session', {
      keepalive: true,
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`,
        'sessionId': `${this.userSessionId}`
      },
    });
  }
```

How can I get this api call to work on IE?

Comment: try to return false as last statement of your method

Comment: the Fetch API isn't available on IE. Why not using HttpClient as it's the standard with Angular?

Comment: Can you try in explorer when developer console is open and tell result ?

Comment: @pc_coder I'm not sure how I can do that as this is supposed to happen when the user closes the tab/browser

Comment: In angular you should use HttpClient rather than fetch.

Comment: @GeromeGrignon for my normal api call I am using HttpClient. What I am trying to accomplish is an API call after the user closes the browser/tab. When I try calling the method from my service in onBeforeUnload, the browser closes too fast and the method isn't called.

Comment: @pc_coder refer to my comment to GeromeGrignon

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Avoid making too much updates to a question as the previous comments and answers don't make sense anymore and might confuse people reading it

Comment: you can ask a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: `fetch` is not supported in `IE11`, you need a polyfill - https://github.com/github/fetch