# Calling my logout function on browser close Angular isn't working, how to fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, service

I have a method logout() that logs the user out and updates the database that the user is logged out. I want to be able to make that call in the event that the user closes the browser or tab. The following isn't working:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(): boolean {

    let logout: any;
    logout = logout();
    while (logout = false) {
      console.log("session not ended")
    }
    return true;

  }

  public async logout(): Promise<boolean> {
    this.userSessionService.EndSession(this.userSessionId);
    this.oauthService.logOut(false);
    return true;
  }
```

How can I make these calls on browser close to update the database?

Comment: please avoid to post a question more than once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030052/onbeforeunload-doesnt-call-methods-browser-closes-too-fast

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onBeforeUnload doesn't call methods, browser closes too fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030052/onbeforeunload-doesnt-call-methods-browser-closes-too-fast)